# Xamarin .NET API using Refit error Refit.ApiException

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, exception, refit

I face an error from refit.
In development, i run API on local IIS and no issue. When i put on IIS server i got a

> Refit.ApiException: Response status code does not indicate success:
> 500 (Internal Server Error). at
> Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2[T,TBody].b__0
> (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, System.Threading.CancellationToken
> ct, System.Object[] paramList) [0x00336] in
> /_/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:267 at
> VisiBukkuClient.LoginScreen.b__9_0 (System.Object , System.EventArgs )
> [0x001e7] in D:\VisiBukkuClient\LoginScreen.cs:106

i try to solve this issue for a week, but no result.
anyone please help, thank you.

Comment: `...500 (Internal Server Error)....` Have you looked in the server log?

Comment: @Denny ow did you solve it? I mean, what was the exact problem?

Comment: @Demobilizer from IIS side i make some little things that make app work on VPN connection